# Conditional probability on multiple conditions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I want to calculate probabilities like

$$P(B_1=1,B_2=0,B_3=0\mid C_1=1, C_2=1, C_3=0)$$

I know the separate pairwise conditional probabilities like

$P(B_1=1\mid C_1=1)$ for all $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ and $C_1,\ldots,C_n$

Can i utilize them and build joint probability?

Comment: These data are not sufficient to deduce the conditional probability you are interested in.